# How can I authenticate a user without login form in vanilla node.js?

Tags: node.js, http

I'm creating a blog site where I can post, delete and edit blogs. I want the users to be able to upvote the posts, but I don't know how to authenticate them. I don't want to use a login system because I think it would be an overkill for my current project.

This is my current solution for the problem, but it not really works:

- I want to get the user's local IPv4 address so I can store it and I can save things to it.

```
const http = require("http");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url == "/") {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end();
        console.log(req.headers["x-forwarded-for"]);
    };
});

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

It's just a demo to show what is my problem with this **req.headers["x-forwarded-for"]** method. It returns the user's public IP address, so for example if someone in a network would upvote a blog then a different user on the same network would see that he upvoted that specific blog but in reality the user never liked the blog.

Is there a way to get the user's IPv4 addresses? Maybe there is another solution to authenticate a user without the IP method? I think somehow it's possible because I saw a site where I could upvote images without login or anything like this and it worked on my phone and pc correctly.

Comment: If they are in a windows network with active directory, you can use https://github.com/abbr/NodeSSPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to handle upvotes without authentication, you can consider using cookies to store a user id. This would keep the voting status uniform across all networks for that browser only (unless you clear browser data).

Explanation:

1. If there is no cookie, the frontend can create a random string as the user-id and store it in a cookie.
2. For each vote, the frontend sends the user-id in the cookie with the blog data, and the backend updates the votes.
3. On retrieving data, the frontend compares the users with the user-id stored in the cookie to show which blogs were voted by the user.

Drawbacks:

1. If the user opens the blog on another browser or clears browser data, you will have inconsistencies in the db.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is going to be the best way to do it.